# how to use ActorSink.actorRefWithBackpressure in akka stream using akka typed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-typed

i am trying to learn akka streams using akka typed the documentations is bit abstract when it comes to akka typed

the [Sink.actorRefWithBackpressure](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6.6/stream/operators/Sink/actorRefWithBackpressure.html)
 example is pretty straightforward and easy to understand where as 
[ActorSink.actorRefWithBackpressure](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6.6/stream/operators/ActorSink/actorRefWithBackpressure.html)
 example is abstract

in the first example we have `AckingReceiver` actor which does the required work but when it comes to second example

there is no implementation of case classes as it was in `AckingReceiver`

```
val actor: ActorRef[Protocol] = targetActor()
```

i have seen this code some where  but i am unable to understand it as well

```
def targetActor(): ActorRef[Protocol] = ???
```

how can we provide the implementation of target actor which deals with case classes 
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActorRef[Protocol]` is a typed actor like any other.  Obtaining an `ActorRef` outside of the `ActorSystem` in typed is somewhat more involved than in classic, which is likely why the docs elide that (as it's not important for explaining how to use `ActorSink.actorRefWithBackpressure`).

Typically you would setup a typed `ActorSystem` and ask that `ActorSystem` for an `ActorRef`:

```
import akka.actor.typed.ActorRef
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl._

object MainSystem {
  sealed trait Command
  case class ObtainProtocolActor(replyTo: ActorRef[ProtocolActorIs])

  sealed trait Reply
  case class ProtocolActorIs(actor: ActorRef[Protocol])

  def apply(): Behavior[Command] =
    Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
      case ObtainProtocolActor(replyTo) =>
        val protocolActor: ActorRef[Protocol] = context.spawnAnonymous(
          // Define the protocol actor
          Behaviors.receive[Protocol] { (context, msg) =>
            case Init(ackTo) =>
              println(s"Actor ${context.self.path} initializing")
              ackTo ! Ack
              Behaviors.same
            case Message(ackTo, msg) =>
              println(s"Actor ${context.self.path} received $msg")
              ackTo ! Ack
              Behaviors.same
            case Complete =>
              context.stop()  // Delayed until the message is processed
              ackTo ! Ack
              Behaviors.same
            case Fail(ex) =>
              println(s"Actor ${context.self.path} got failure from stream: ${ex.getMessage}")
              Behaviors.same
          })
        context.watch(protocolActor)
        replyTo ! ProtocolActorIs(protocolActor)
    }.receiveSignal {
      case (context, Terminated(ref)) =>
        println(s"Actor ${ref.path} terminated")
    }
}

val actorSystem = ActorSystem(MainSystem(), "main")

def targetActor(): ActorRef[Protocol] = Await.result(
  actorSystem.ask(MainSystem.ObtainProtocolActor(_)).map(_.replyTo),
  15.second
)
```

This shows probably the two biggest practical, but perhaps non-obvious, differences between classic and typed:

- the `ActorSystem` in typed is an actor (it's actually possible to have an `ActorRef[Protocol]` in this example be the `ActorSystem`, though it's unlikely you'd actually want to do this)
- the ask pattern is changed in a fairly dramatic way